# If MySQL row output equals X then do Y

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

What I'm trying to achieve here is to change the output. 
The rows minutes, sms or data can output -1 as the result.  All I want to do is have it so if the output from any row is -1, then it should output "Unlimited" instead.

This is done with CodeIgniter.

```
foreach ($getprices->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->price;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $row->minutes;
   echo "<br>";
   echo $row->sms;   
   echo "<br>";
   echo $row->data;   
   echo "<br><hr>";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer:

```
echo ($row->price == -1) ? 'Unlimited' : $row->price;
```

Do this for each output you have.

Comment: Ah, nice and simple thanks.  I was looking at it in too much detail trying to kill all options off in one!

Comment: Yeah sometimes there's just no need to get complicated. :-)

Answer (score 4):

To use [mysql if statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

```
SELECT price
     , IF(minutes = -1, 'Unlimited', minutes) as minutes
     , IF(sms = -1, 'Unlimited', sms) as sms
     , IF(data = -1,'Unlimited', data) as data
<...>
```

But I prefer handling it in PHP it self, just like @phpisuber01 suggested.